# タグ "lua" のコード言語に lang-lua を設定して欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

現在、タグ:[lua](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) のコード言語 (構文の強調表示に使用されるもの)に何も設定されていないようなので、`lang-lua` を設定していただければと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

設定いたしました✅

[image: lang-lua を設定した画面です]